# sed is ignoring quotation in a replacement string

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace a string in a line with another string with quotation marks in a file, say, $FILE. I'm trying to use sed.

I want to replace `m     = uniform(0, 0, 1)` by `m.LoadFile("run2_initial_$NF.ovf")`

I am using this:

```
sed -i 's#m     = uniform(0, 0, 1)#m.LoadFile("run2_initial_$NF.ovf")#g' $FILE
```

What I am getting is `m     = uniform(0, 0, 1)` replaced by `m.LoadFile(run2_initial_$NF.ovf)`

That is, sed is just ignoring the quotation marks in the replacement string.

Am I doing something stupid?

Please suggest.

Edit: The quotation mark is now working fine, when I try now. Though the $NF is not being replaced by a number :(

What I got in the new file is:

m.LoadFile("run2_initial_$NF.ovf")

whereas I wanted: m.LoadFile("run2_initial_3.ovf")

Comment: Your command, as shown, works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, you are right, not sure what was happening earlier. I edited the question now. Now there is a new problem!

Comment: `$NF` is an `awk` concept, not a `sed` concept.

Comment: no, $NF is just a variable for me, what I am doing is: file=$NotFlippedList
 while read NF;
  do sed -i 's/${m     = uniform(0, 0, 1)}/${m.LoadFile("run2_initial_$NF.ovf")}/g' run2_$NF.mx3 done

Comment: That is, I have a list of numbers in the file $NotFlippedList. the variable NF is a number read from the list. Then I am trying to use the variable $NF in the sed command.

Comment: please edit your question and format you data and code using the `{}` tool at the top left. Trying to read this as comments is not helpful to problem solving. Give us one, clear, unambiguous description of the problem you're trying to solve and we can probably help. Good luck!

Comment: AND, if you're trying to access a shell variable value (i.e. $NF), you have to quote your `sed` command with dbl-quotes, i.e. `sed "s/..../$NF..../" file` (and deal with any shell chars that need to be escaped). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter and John1024 ! replacing the single quote with double quotes solved the problem. Sorry about the poor formatting, today is my first day at stackexchange :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use double quotes, the variables inside the string will be replaced by their values, if you use single quotes, they won't.

What you need to do here is to replace the single quotes with double quotes, and escape the double quotes you already had:

```
$ echo "m     = uniform(0, 0, 1)" | \
  sed "s#m     = uniform(0, 0, 1)#m.LoadFile(\"run2_initial_$NF.ovf\")#g"
m.LoadFile("run2_initial_3.ovf")
```